# Pass bash script arguments to ansible command in script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ansible

I'm trying to run this command from a bash script and pass the extra-vars from the bash arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook.yml --extra-vars "var1=1 $@" > /path/to/log/file
```

I run the script like below and get this error:

```
> ./test.bs var2=2 var3=3
ERROR! the playbook: var3=3 could not be found
```

I even tried escaping the quotes but it didn't work.
How can I get this to run?

Comment: `"$@"` expands to multiple separate arguments. Thus, `"var1=1 var2=2" "var3=3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you can change your script to use $*:

```
#!/bin/bash
ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook.yml --extra-vars "var1=1 $*" > /path/to/log/file
```

Comment: While rarely true, this is actually a case where `$*` is might actually be the Right Thing, at least if the values are guaranteed to not get too interesting.

Comment: I chose this answer because of the simplicity.
Can you explain why this works though ?

Comment: Sure.  "$@" puts quotes around each command-line argument, and $* does not.  So "$@" comes out to '"var2=2" "var3=3"', and "$*" comes out to '"var2=2 var3=3"'.  Since ansible-playbook is expecting one and only one argument to --extra-args, so it all has to be in a single pair of quotes: "var1=1 var2=2 var3=3".  "$@" will put in quotes you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're on Ansible 1.2 or newer, the most robust thing to do is use `jq` to generate JSON. The following will do this for an arbitrary number of key=value arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
jq_args=( )
jq_text='{}'

i=0
for arg in var1=1 "$@"; do
  [[ $arg = *=* ]] || continue # require arguments to be in key=value form
  key=${arg%%=*}
  value=${arg#*=}
  jq_args+=( --arg "key$i" "$key" --arg "value$i" "$value" )
  jq_text+=" | .[\$key$i]=\$value$i"
  ((i++))
done

json_final=$(jq "${jq_args[@]}" "$jq_text" <<<"$json") # || exit

ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook.yml --extra-vars "$json_final"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing one long argument to `--extra-vars` since it's all within the same `"` marks.  You are building a single string of `var1=1 arg1 arg2 arg3`.

Your intention was likely to instead pass three arguments, each one a string that look like `var1=1` `var2=2` `var3=3`

With that said, try this.

`ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook.yml --extra-vars "var1=1" "$@" > /path/to/log/file`

This way you are passing the first arg as the string `"var1=1"` and then bash expands `"$@"` into the individual arguments that you've passed to the program.

So with the above snippet `./test.bs var2=2 var3=3` will properly execute.  For sanity though it's good practice to wrap your args in `"` though in this case its not necessary.  It's good to get in the habit though since one day you'll run `./test.bs var2=*` and get some crazy output.  So the final, most sane, call would be...

`./test.bs "var2=2" "var3=3"`

Comment: "Passing one long argument"? Not true; `"$@"` causes splits between distinct arguments to be preserved. Try running `set -- one two three; printf '<%s>\n' "start$@end"`, and you'll see `startone` as the first argument, `two` as the second, and `threeend` as the last. Compare to the same but with `"start$*end"` -- in *that* case everything's passed as just one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Run it like this:

```
> ./test.bs 'var2=2 var3=3'
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems correct and should work.

Quoting and not quoting `var1=1 $@` will make a difference only for the way the arguments are passed in. Not quoting it will allow arguments to be passed quoted (i.e. `"var2=2 var3=3"`) or unquoted (i.e. `var2=2 var3=3`) as it will expand space separated arguments into separate arguments. If `$@` is quoted, the arguments must be passed not quoted or individually quotted (i.e. `"var2=2" "var3=3"`) so they are accepted as individual arguments.

One option that would work for sure is using `eval`, however, that is usually avoided as it allows passing unsafe data. Bascially just put `eval` before the command:

```
eval ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook.yml --extra-vars "var1=1 $@" \
    > /path/to/log/file
```

It will go through the command, parsing it and removing all first level quotes, making the command `ansib ... --extra-vars var1=1 var2=2 var3=3 > /path...`.

Comment: That's not the correct form for `--extra-vars`. It expects a single argument to follow -- ie. from http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line, see the example with `ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "version=1.23.45 other_variable=foo"`

Comment: and frankly, if you did want to pass one argument per variable, why would you use `eval` rather than make it `--extra-vars "var1=1" "$@"`?

Comment: (The use of `eval` also exposes your data to parsing as code -- if `$@` had an argument originally specified as `var4='$(rm -rf ~)'`, someone would have a very bad day).